# fetch the data from multiple api - axios and get it in the page on load vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, web-frontend

I want to fetch the data from multiple `API` with `axios` in Vue.js 3. The backend is Laravel API.

I am able to get data on response1.data and response2.data on console but how can I assign this data to the object defined on data() function of Vue.js.

I need this data to load on page on loaded. The Vue.js code is -

```
<script>
export default {
  name:'Followup',
  data() {
    return {
      patient:{},
      labGroup:{},
    }
  },
  created() {     
    this.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      this.$axios.all([
        this.$axios.get(`/api/patients/showSomeDetails/${this.$route.params.id}`),
         this.$axios.get('/api/labitems/getGroup')
      ])
      .then(this.$axios.spread(function (response1, response2) {
          console.log(response1.data) // this has given result on console. 
          this.patient = response1.data  // It is giving error on console. => TypeError: Cannot set property 'patient' of null
          this.labGroup = response2.data // same
          console.log(response2.data)

        }))
        .catch(function (error) {
           console.error(error);
        });

        })
    },
computed() {
},
methods: {
}
} 
</script>
```

I got error on console - this- `app.js:20666 TypeError: Cannot set property 'patient' of null`

How can I assign data to the patient and labGroup, so it will applied to my webpage via v-model

This is my patient followup up form, where I need to get the patient details from patient table, and labitems to fill lab reports from labitems table.

I hope, someone will give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `this` in `function (response1, response2) {` wont be the vue instance.

Either use an arrow function or bind `this` to the `function (response1, response2) { ... }.bind(this)`

Comment: It worked with both arrow function and or with normal function and adding bind.this.

Answer (score 0):

**First Option:**

You can use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) property of vue.js and before rendering `patient` property you need add `v-if` as below so that it won't be rendered on DOM until it has some truthy value.

**template:**

`<div v-if="patient">{{patient}} </div>`

**script:**

```
watch: {
    // whenever patient changes, this function will run
    patient: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      this.patient= newValue;
    }
  }
```

**Second Option:**
Wrap your get calls inside `getPatient` method by `awaiting` it render `patient` once data is bound to it.

**template:**

`<div v-if="patient">{{patient}} </div>`

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Followup',
    data() {
        return {
            patient: null,
            labGroup: null,
        };
    },
    created() {
        await this.getPatient();
    },
    computed() {},
    methods: {
        async getPatient() {
            await this.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((response) => {
                this.$axios
                    .all([this.$axios.get(`/api/patients/showSomeDetails/${this.$route.params.id}`), this.$axios.get('/api/labitems/getGroup')])
                    .then(
                        this.$axios.spread(function (response1, response2) {
                            console.log(response1.data); // this has given result on console.
                            this.patient = response1.data; // It is giving error on console. => TypeError: Cannot set property 'patient' of null
                            this.labGroup = response2.data; // same
                            console.log(response2.data);
                        })
                    )
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```